# noclassdefFoundError after running update

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Hi I'm new to android development. I took over a project when someone left my company recently and I was able to build and run the app ok. Since running an update on eclipse I can no longer run the app, I get this error:

```
07-29 10:27:13.843: E/AndroidRuntime(314): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-29 10:27:13.843: E/AndroidRuntime(314): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: uk.co.mosquitodigital.panic.dao.DaoMaster
07-29 10:27:13.843: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at uk.co.mosquitodigital.panic.dao.DaoMaster$OpenHelper.onCreate(DaoMaster.java:48)
07-29 10:27:13.843: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
07-29 10:27:13.843: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at uk.co.mosquitodigital.panic.PanicApplication.onCreate(PanicApplication.java:64)
07-29 10:27:13.843: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:969)
07-29 10:27:13.843: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4244)
07-29 10:27:13.843: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3000(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-29 10:27:13.843: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2071)
07-29 10:27:13.843: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-29 10:27:13.843: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-29 10:27:13.843: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-29 10:27:13.843: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-29 10:27:13.843: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-29 10:27:13.843: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-29 10:27:13.843: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-29 10:27:13.843: E/AndroidRuntime(314):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are only three reasons you will ever get this error:

1. The class genuinely doesn't exist. If you are using code from an official example and getting this, make sure you have the latest build of the library
2. You have not added the jar to your build path. To fix this, right click on the jar in Eclipse, and do Build Path ► Add to Build Path.
3. Your jar is not in the /libs folder. This happens when you have added the jar to the build path, but newer versions of ADT need it to be in /libs. Put it there and re-add it to the build path.

Mostly, such errors occur because newer versions of the ADT require all external jars to be in the libs folder. Your colleague was probably on a different version than you, and hence the error.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I cant see a 'libs' folder in my project?

Comment: You will have to create it. It doesn't exits by default

Comment: Ok I right clicked on the project gone to 'build path' > 'configure build path' and added the lib folder on the source tab... is this correct?

Comment: Right click on the project, and Go to New -> Folder. Create one called 'libs'. With an 's'. Now put the Jar files in it. Now add each jar to the build path individually, by right clicking on it, and going to Build Path -> Add to Build Path

Comment: tried to add an image to show you what i have but stack overflow wont let me because of my level. i right clicked on the first jar file which is android.jar > build path > i dont have 'add to build path listed just configure...

Comment: Did you remove the old jar from the build path first?

Comment: ahh, got it to work... well sort of... i now get 
[2012-07-30 09:20:03 - panic] Failed to install panic.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2012-07-30 09:20:03 - panic] (null)
[2012-07-30 09:20:03 - panic] Launch canceled!

Comment: That's a problem with your connection to the emulator, and hence not related to this question.

Comment: fixed, i reinstalled the emulator, but now when the emulator does run i get the same error as before :-( defintly referencing my jars from just the libs folder

Comment: Are you sure the emulator supports the functionality you're trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

**1.** First thing you must do is to **Clean the project.**

**2.** Properly **configure the Build Path**.

**3.** If there are **external Libraries**, then **create a "libs" folder in your project, and then
       configure the Build Path.**

**4. Restart** your Eclipse

Comment: The newer tools require the folder to be called "libs"